# low object confidence scores while training yolov2 for face-non face dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

Currently i am working on an object detection problem which involves detecting faces in an images  and creating boxes around them.
To address this issue , i have created a yolov2 model as described in the paper with loss function as mentioned in the paper itlself. At earlier stages i was facing the issue of Nan losses for localization loss and hence unstable training. Hence  found a workaround by making some small changes in loss function. Presently the issue i am facing is with very low object confidence score, as i am dealing with face-no_face dataset ,the class score during inference is 1.0 but the object confidence score is very lesss for many of the instances which contain only one face , let alone multiple faces in an image. Though while training the cummulative loss is saturating around 0.06 , but while inference , there is whole new picture of very less confidence score.

Loss function : The loss function i am using for calculating confidence score is cummumative loss of two terms : no_object_loss and object_loss and both are MSE losses for grid cells which has object (object_loss) and rest contribute to no_object_loss.

Note : My dataset contains 4996 instances of multi face images and ONLY 4 INSTANCES OF NO FACE. and so i was wondering if this is the issue as i why i am getting low object confidence scores.

Comment: is it possible to see your loss function ? also, did you try some stuff for imbalanced dataset ? i think you can pass in `class_weights`in keras. check [this thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653)

Comment: @SiddhantTandon the loss function is a combined loss of four terms , localization_loss , no_objecT_loss , object_loss and class_loss. All the losses are MSE of prediction and ground truth with some preprocssing of predictions except class loss if a version of Cross entropy. I am using Tensorflow 1.15 as backend , using scale values for all the four loss terms to regulate the effect on the loss function . Its a replication of the loss function described in the yolo paper. You can look it up  (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287486/yolo-loss-function-explanation)

Answer (score 2):

i am posting the answer here , in case if someone goes through same issue they can follow the same debugging steps , 
So first i figured what was the cause of low combined scores , and it turned out that it was the object scores which were very less , 
So i looked at the distribution of the activations after each loss and also the behaviour of object loss , seemed like it was fluctuating a lot , which suggested that the loss from this particular term was not according to the desired pattern . 
hence i recursed back to the loss function and fortunately the mistake was in the IOU calculation of the loss function . 
The problem was basically with the bounds of the iou calculation , i.e there was no bounds on what the intersection of two boxes can be , so the range  of the intersection can from -inf to +inf. Hence the iou was coming to be huge lot of times , but intuitively iou can be only from 0 to 1 and . 
the solution to it was to truncate the localisation of predictions from 0 to image height and image width during preprocessing for iou calculation. also, while calculating the iou which is intersection / union , i made sure that intersection is greater or equal to 0 (not less than which means that there is not intersection at all).
Doing this helped the model learn in a lot correct and better way to predict boxes whenever it can .